# What on EARTH is this eggs.js thing?

Tags: support, chat, fun, javascript

So, [whilst perusing the src for the chat.Travel.SE page to see if the background of the bottom chat bar showed where you were in the world](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26729961#26729961) (which would be cool, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)), I found a handy little JS file called [eggs.js](http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Js/eggs.js?v=3).

It had some pretty interesting stuff in it, such as `Eggs.Asteroids` and `Eggs.Cthulu`. My favorite was:

> `["The <center> cannot hold it is too late.", "You can't parse [X]HTML with regex.", "Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.", "The use of regex will not allow you to consume HTML.", "Russian hackers pwn your webapp", "ALL IS LOST ALL IS LOST", "ZALGO IS TONY THE PONY HE COMES", "so many times but it is not getting to me.", "HTML is not a regular language", "not equipped to break down HTML into its meaningful parts", "go no NO NOOOO NO stop the angles are not real", "we cannot be saved", "You will never make me crack.", "a breach between this world and the dread realm of corrupt entities", "Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions.", "the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins", "it is too late it is too late", "an eternity of dread torture and security holes", "your psyche withering in the onslaught of horror", "will destroy your mind like so much watery putty", "his unholy radiance destroying all enlightenmnent", "HTML tags leaking from your eyes like liquid pain", "I can see it can you see it", "the One whose Name cannot be expressed in the Basic Multilingual Plane", "summons tainted souls into the realm of the living", "the pony he comes he comes he comes", "regex will consume all living tissue", "the ichor permeates all MY FACE MY FACE"];`

What on earth is this? Is this a remnant of StackEgg? And, most importantly, why on earth is it here, in a chat.SE page, and what is it doing?